# aggregating with a condition in groupby spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe

```
id lat long lag_lat lag_long detector lag_interval  gpsdt  lead_gpsdt
  1  12   13    12       13        1        [1.5,3.5]  4      4.5
  1  12   13    12       13        1        null       4.5    5
  1  12   13    12       13        1        null       5      5.5
  1  12   13    12       13        1        null       5.5    6
  1  13   14    12       13        2        null       6      6.5
  1  13   14    13       14        2        null       6.5    null
  2  13   14    13       14        2        [0.5,1.5]  2.5    3.5  
  2  13   14    13       14        2        null       3.5    4 
  2  13   14    13       14        2        null       4      null
```

so I wanted to apply a condition while using groupby in agg function that if we do groupby col("id") and col("detector")  then I want to check the condition that if lag_interval in that group has any non-null value then in aggregation I want two columns one is

```
 min("lag_interval.col1") and other is max("lead_gpsdt")
```

If the above condition is not met then I want

```
min("gpsdt"), max("lead_gpsdt")
```

using this approach I want to get the data with a condition

```
df.groupBy("detector","id").agg(first("lat-long").alias("start_coordinate"),
    last("lat-long").alias("end_coordinate"),struct(min("gpsdt"), max("lead_gpsdt")).as("interval"))
```

output

```
  id interval  start_coordinate end_coordinate
  1   [1.5,6]      [12,13]         [13,14] 
  1   [6,6.5]      [13,14]         [13,14]
  2   [0.5,4]      [13,14]         [13,14]
```

**

*for more explanation*

**
if we see a part of what groupby("id","detector") does is taking a part out,

we have to see that if in that group of data if one of the value in the col("lag_interval") is not null then we need to use aggregation like this *min(lag_interval.col1),max(lead_gpsdt)*
this condition will apply to below set of data

```
id lat long lag_lat lag_long detector lag_interval  gpsdt  lead_gpsdt
 1  12   13    12       13        1        [1.5,3.5]  4      4.5
 1  12   13    12       13        1        null       4.5    5
 1  12   13    12       13        1        null       5      5.5
 1  12   13    12       13        1        null       5.5    6
```

and if the all value of col("lag_interval") is null in that group of data then we need aggregation output as 
*min("gpsdt"),max("lead_gpsdt")*
this condition will apply to below set of data

```
id lat long lag_lat lag_long detector lag_interval  gpsdt  lead_gpsdt
 1  13   14    12       13        2        null       6      6.5
 1  13   14    13       14        2        null       6.5    null
```

Comment: Is that the output for the given input? can you elaborate a little more ?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yes sir,I have updated an elaborate explanation for the output

Comment: is lag_interval  a struct column? can you also share the schema of input dataframe?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yes its a struct

Comment: what is first("lat-long") and last("lat-long")? there is no such column as lat-long is there? see my answer below if it helps

Comment: @RameshMaharjan lat-long is the struct of lat and long

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The conditional dilemma* that you have should be solved by using simple `when` *inbuilt function* as suggested below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.groupBy("id","detector")
  .agg(
    struct(
      when(isnull(min("lag_interval.col1")), min("gpsdt")).otherwise(min("lag_interval.col1")).as("min"),
      max("lead_gpsdt").as(("max"))
    ).as("interval")
  )
```

which should give you output as

```
+---+--------+----------+
|id |detector|interval  |
+---+--------+----------+
|2  |2       |[0.5, 4.0]|
|1  |2       |[6.0, 6.5]|
|1  |1       |[1.5, 6.0]|
+---+--------+----------+
```

and I guess you must already have idea how to do `first("lat-long").alias("start_coordinate"), last("lat-long").alias("end_coordinate")` as you have done.

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: sir what are your views on persisting a dataframe and how to use it again?

Comment: you can use persist or cache. both saves data so that whenever you perform an action on a persisted or cached data, it is not recomputed from scratch. using the cached data is as usual for any other computations.

Comment: okay got it, I am not able to get how to use cached/persisted dataframe for further use.